# Bootstrap carousel disappears each time before the next image is loaded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Im Using Joomla 3.0 with bootstrap framework, thought including a slider through something that is already loaded is a good idea...

All seems to work fine, but there are few annoying things that i just don't seem to be able to figure out,

Carousel loads find, but when time for next slide comes, the whole slider disappears to the top and then there is a 1 second gap and then slider appears (down from the top) with the next image....

http://radiustrade.com (username: test , password test)

Much appreciated whoever can help me sort this out...

Comment: Found that disabling mootools, has helped, must have been a fighting issue of some sort...